# Extending express-validator/node-validator to work with req.files

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express

I'm trying to extend expressValidator to add my custom rule for checking if req.files is coming in as an image. Because express-validator uses node-validator, and node-validator parses the request body for the input parameter:

`req.body.email` is passed in as `req.assert('email', 'Please enter a valid Email').isEmail()`, so anything passed into `req.assert()` with express-validator needs to be the parameter name.

This is where I'm running into a problem, because I have my method I wrote here:

```
  expressValidator.Validator.prototype.isImage = function() {
    var type          = this.str,
        allowedTypes  = ['gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'],
        allowed       = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < allowedTypes.length; i++) {
      if (type.indexOf(allowedTypes[i]) !== -1) {
        allowed = true;
      }
    }

    if (!allowed) {
      this.error(this.msg);
    }
    return this;
  };
```

But I can't just do `req.assert('avatar', 'Please enter a valid image type').isImage()` because for one, I need to pass in the `req.files.avatar.type`. With `req.assert()`, the first parameter expects a string.

If I do give it the string: e.g. `req.assert(req.files.avatar.type, 'Please enter a valid image type').isImage()` in my error message object, it'll show this:

```
{ 'image/png':
   { param: 'image/png',
     msg: 'Please enter a valid image',
     value: undefined } 
}
```

When it should be showing this:

```
{ 'avatar':
   { param: 'avatar',
     msg: 'Please enter a valid image',
     value: 'image/png' } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I did something similar. But my approach is a little different, more kinda hack. But since no one answered, I will try to help :)

I wrote a generic error generation vaildator.prototype

```
expressValidator.Validator.prototype.genError = function() {
  this.error(this.msg);
  return this;
};
```

Then while validating,

```
var validate_profile = function(req, next) {
  async.series([
    function(callback) {
      req.assert('name', 'Please provide your name.').notEmpty().notNull();
      .........
    },
function(callback) {
  // Validate image size for profile_picture
  if(req.files.profile_picture && req.files.profile_picture.size === 0) {
    req.assert('profile_picture', 'Profile picture is required').genError();
  }
  if(req.files.profile_picture && req.files.profile_picture.size > 0) {
    imageMagick(req.files.profile_picture.path).size(function(err, size) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if(size.width < 1200) {
      req.assert('profile_picture', 'Profile picture should have atleast 1200px width').genError();
      callback(null);
    } else callback(null);
    .......
```

This works for me perfectly. Your approach is of-course better, but this works as well :)